# Power Analysis on test statistic that is the difference of average of proportions

Tags: statistical-power

How do I do a power analysis on a test statistic that is the difference of the average of proportions?

As a contrived example, suppose there is an experiment where we have N teachers, each with varying number of students. We want to test the effectiveness of giving some technology to a teacher on their student's pass rates.

Suppose the proposed experiment is give half the teachers the technology and have half the teachers as a held out control. Suppose each student takes only one exam, graded as pass/fail. For each teacher, we calculate the proportion of their students who pass the exam.

We then want to compare the average of this proportion between the treatment and control group in order to calculate how many teachers we need and how many students we need.

I'm having trouble with this because in a straightforward power calculation, the intervention is done at the same level as the observational units. But in this case, it seems like the intervention is done at a "higher" level than the observational unit (test score).

Comment: There may be an issue of whether / how you deal with the "teacher"/"class" random effect (it would be difficult to separate those unless some teachers had more than one class say)

Comment: As a simplifying assumption, suppose a teacher only teaches one class of students, and each student is only assigned to one teacher. Does that simplify/clarify?

Comment: It is a cluster randomized trial, for which there should be a literature on power calculations.

Comment: Oh, and just calculating the proportion for each teacher will be very inefficient,  if the number of pupils varies substantially between teachers - 1/1 passing should not be given the same influence as 30/30 passing. See also Glen_b's comment.

Comment: @Björn thanks -- for future readers, this is one such paper in the literature for power calculations in cluster randomized trials https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4521133/